# Inner joins with 2 foreign keys to one primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a table called 
branch (branchid, branchname)
and another table called transfer
transfer(tranferid, sourcebranch, destinationbranch)

both sourcebranch and destinationbranch are Fk to the branchid of of branch table.
I need to show a query that looks like this

**Tranferid   Source   Destination
   4          uk        us**

but all I can get is something like this

**Tranferid   Source   Destinationid
   4          uk        3**

query sample

*select tranferid, branch.branchname, transfer.destinationbranch
from transfer
inner join branch on branch.branchid == transfer.sourcebranch*

How do I get the destination branch to show. CTE on my mind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to join table `branch` on table `transfer` twice so you can get the value for each column.

```
SELECT  a.*, 
        b.branchName AS sourceBranchName,
        c.branchName AS destinationBranchName
FROM    transfer a
        INNER JOIN branch b
            ON a.sourcebranch = b.branchID
        INNER JOIN branch c
            ON a.destinationbranch = c.branchID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Comment: Thanks, I tried that previous and got something else, I guess I made a mistake initially with my join conditions. Thanks a million.